# Combining multiple columns in R?

Tags: r

Is there a way to shift a group of columns into their own row in R?

I currently have large a dataset that includes column headings like this:

| Month | Year | Tenant 1 Name | Tenant 1 Rate | Tenant 1 Vacate Date | Tenant 1 Notes | Tenant 1 Name | Tenant 2 Rate | Tenant 2 Vacate Date | Tenant 2 Notes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jan | 2001 | Bob | 1 | 2 | 3 | Joe | 1 | 2 | 3 |

I want to combine this information so that each Tenant within each month and year have their own rows. So the rows would just be like this:

| Month | Year | Name | Rate | Date | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jan | 2001 | Bob | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| Jan | 2001 | Joe | 1 | 2 | 3 |

I assume this would be something like group_by() but for multiple columns somehow?

Sorry for the clumsy formatting!

Answer (score 2):

First, to generate an example like yours (your example had "Tenant 1 Name" twice, but I guess it was just a typo).

```
colnames<-c("Month","Year","Tenant 1 Name","Tenant 1 Rate","Tenant 1 Vacate Date","Tenant 1 Notes","Tenant 2 Name","Tenant 2 Rate","Tenant 2 Vacate Date","Tenant 2 Notes")
fields<-c("Jan","2001","Bob","1","2","3","Joe","1","2","3")
mat<-matrix(fields,nrow=1)
colnames(mat)<-colnames
View(mat)
```

It will look like this:

[image: Your example]

Now, identify which column have "Name" in them

```
cols<-grep("Name",colnames(mat))
cols
```

Then, extract names from those columns:

```
names<-mat[,cols]
```

And finally, filla new matrix:

```
newmat<-matrix(NA,nrow=0,ncol=6)
for(n in names){
    whichcol<-which(mat[1,]==n)
    newline<-c(mat[,1:2],mat[,whichcol:(whichcol+3)])
    newmat<-rbind(newmat,newline)
}
View(newmat)
```

It will result in what you are looking for:

[image: newresults]

However, I have a feeling that the dataset you are working with has more layers of complexity (e.g., multiple lines), requiring a more complex solution. Please let us know if that's the case!

Answer (score 2):

If the column name for 'Joe' is 'Tenant 2 Name', use `pivot_longer`, specify the `cols` as all except the 'Month', 'Year', and with `names_pattern`, capture the column name substring as the characters that are not a space (`\\S+`) at the end (`$`) of the string

```
library(tidyr)
pivot_longer(df1, cols = -c(Month, Year), 
     names_to = ".value", names_pattern = ".*\\s+(\\S+)$")
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 x 6
#  Month  Year Name   Rate  Date Notes
#  <chr> <int> <chr> <int> <int> <int>
#1 Jan    2001 Bob       1     2     3
#2 Jan    2001 Joe       1     2     3
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Month = "Jan", Year = 2001L, `Tenant 1 Name` = "Bob", 
    `Tenant 1 Rate` = 1L, `Tenant 1 Vacate Date` = 2L, `Tenant 1 Notes` = 3L, 
    `Tenant 2 Name` = "Joe", `Tenant 2 Rate` = 1L, `Tenant 2 Vacate Date` = 2L, 
    `Tenant 2 Notes` = 3L), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L))
```

Comment: Dear Arun, may I ask for your opinion on the regex I used. Do you think there might be cases that it does not live up to expectations in this question?

Comment: @AnoushiravanR I wondered why you capture 3 groups, but the option to specify `NA` was good to know because I was not aware that it would drop those groups

Comment: Regarding the regex used, you are capturing 3 words.  it can be anywhere in the data though. The last one could have `$` at the end to make sure it always selects the last word

Comment: Yeah I found it in the documentations of `pivot_longer` before it give information about `.value` it says we can drop capturing group with `NA`. We can surprisingly use this trick in `separate` function if I'm not mistaken to drop one part of separated columns.

Comment: May be you meant `extract`

Comment: Oh thank you. I just have to take `$` inside my last capturing group? like this `(\\w+$)` ?

Comment: Sometimes, we may think that a particular option may be redundant, but still it gives some great piece of information.  Thank you

Comment: Yes, that would make it more robust

Comment: Yes I wasn't sure it was `extract` because it mostly relies on regex for separation.

Comment: It's a great pleasure to bring it to your attention. Thank you very much indeed.

Answer (score 2):

**Thanks** for the subtle tip from dear @akrun as always. I added a `$` to the last capturing group to make sure it always chooses the last one.
This may sound a bit verbose, but it also does the trick. I created 3 name patterns, turning the first two into `NA` and capture the third one:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 %>% 
  pivot_longer(!c(Month, Year), names_to = c(NA, NA, ".value"),
               names_pattern = "(\\w+) (\\w+) (\\w+$)")

# A tibble: 2 x 6
  Month  Year Name   Rate Vacate Notes
  <chr> <int> <chr> <int>  <int> <int>
1 Jan    2001 Bob       1      2     3
2 Jan    2001 Joe       1      2     3
```